# Azure NodeJS Web Service exists with status code null and signal SIGSEGV

Tags: node.js, azure, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to deploy a NodeJS application to an Azure web service (Node version 10.14, Azure B1 plan), however, when I run the application, it always exists with status **null** and signal **SIGSEGV**.

There were no errors outputted. I tried deploying the same code to Heroku and there were no issues at all.

I tried using the **segfault-handler** module in hopes that it will tell what is wrong, but the only thing that it logs is:

```
PID 147 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x2c26
```

Any ideas what might cause this? One thing I was able to find that it might be related to native modules, but I still don't know which one might cause this.

**EDIT**
The Azure web service uses Linux OS and not Windows.
Modules used:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "apidoc": "^0.17.7",
    "applicationinsights": "^1.3.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.5",
    "chalk": "^2.4.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.6.1",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "excel4node": "^1.7.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-sslify": "^1.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^7.2.0",
    "get-port": "^4.2.0",
    "is-json": "^2.0.1",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "node-cache": "^4.2.0",
    "node-cleanup": "^2.1.2",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.0",
    "number-to-words": "^1.2.4",
    "pdf-to-base64": "^1.0.2",
    "pdfkit": "^0.9.1",
    "pg": "^7.9.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "rate-limiter-flexible": "^1.0.2",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise-native": "^1.0.7",
    "segfault-handler": "^1.2.0",
    "sequelize": "^5.8.7",
    "socketcluster": "^14.3.3",
    "socketcluster-client": "^14.2.2",
    "socketcluster-server": "^14.4.0",
    "systeminformation": "^4.0.15",
    "twilio": "^3.30.0",
    "umzug": "^2.2.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.7",
    "@types/chalk": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
    "@types/dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/joi": "^14.3.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.107",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.6",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.7.35",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.5",
    "@types/request-promise": "^4.1.42",
    "@types/serialize-javascript": "^1.3.2",
    "@types/sinon": "^7.0.11",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.3",
    "casual": "^1.6.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "sinon": "^7.2.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, if there are few node modules related to native apis like `Win32k.sys`, it will be terminated immediately by [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) once run.

Therefore, the possible reason may be these limits and restrictions described in sandbox secure environment, such as below.

[image]

Please inspect your used modules carefully. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But shouldn't this only affect windows servers and not linux?

Comment: @CombustiblePizza Yeah, this only affect windows. Did you deploy on Azure WebApp for Linux? Please update your post about more details, such as what node modules you used.

Comment: Ok, I added the dependency list.